# How to use optional object members?

Tags: typescript, javascript-objects

I have an object that always has two members, and in some conditions, a third one can be added.

**Attempt #1**: optional member

```
let initObject = {
    headers: headers,
    method: method ? 'GET' : method,
    body?: ''
  }
  if (method === 'POST') {
    initObject.body = body
  }
```

This fails with `TS1162: An object member cannot be declared optional.`

**Attempt #2**: forcibly add a member:

```
let initObject = {
    headers: headers,
    method: method ? 'GET' : method,
  }
if (method === 'POST') {
    initObject.body = body
  }
```

This now fails with `TS2339: Property 'body' does not exist on type '{ headers: Headers; method: string; }'.`

**How can I add an optional member to an Object?**

I currently use a workaround, but it is repetitive and I am sure there is a nicer way

```
let initObject
if (method === 'GET') {
    initObject = {
      headers: headers,
      method: 'GET',
    }
  } else if (method === 'POST') {
    initObject = {
      headers: headers,
      method: 'POST',
      body: body
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer from @pzaenger is the best solution, but if you don't want to use an interface maybe use:

```js
const initObject = {
    headers,
    method: method || 'GET',
    body: method === 'POST' ? body : undefined
}
```

Also the ternary condition you're using for `method` doesn't make sense to me

Comment: The ternary was supposed to mean "if `method` is true-ish then use the value, otherwise use `'GET'`". Now: i) I realized that I had it backwards and ii) I switched to a default value of the parameter of the encompassing function (`method` is the parameter)

Comment: Ah, an excellent idea to make `body` `undefined` - this actually fixes my issue (which was TS not accepting a body for `GET` operations)

Answer (score 2):

Use an object type respectively an [interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html) (you still need to set the types properly):

> Each property in an object type can specify a couple of things: the
> type, whether the property is optional, and whether the property can
> be written to.

```
interface InitObject {
  headers: any;
  method: any; // e.g. 'GET' | 'POST'
  body?: any; // body is optional
}

let initObject: InitObject;

...

if (method === 'GET') {
  initObject = {
    headers: headers,
    method: 'GET'
  };
} else if (method === 'POST') {
  initObject = {
    headers: headers,
    method: 'POST',
    body: body
  };
}
```

**Edit:** This also works by using an interface:

```
let initObject: InitObject = {
  headers: headers,
  method: method ? 'GET' : method
};

if (method === 'POST') { // or maybe initObject.method === 'POST'
  initObject.body = body;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what this adds to my workaround? I was expecting a way to avoid repeating pieces of code (= just updating the object if the condition is met).

Comment: @WoJ See my update. I hope it helps :)